# Unable to render Altair chart when saved as HTML

Tags: javascript, python, macos, plotly, altair

I am using Altair to develop an interactive chart. Altair uses plotly in background. Until yesterday I was able to download the interactive chart as an HTML and open in web-browser, still being able to use it interactively. However, now I unable to use it interactively, and it is like a static chart when I open the HTML. The interactivity is there when seen in the jupyter notebook.

I am unsure, but javascript usually helps in rendering the interactivity. This possibly happened after I update my MacOS.

```py
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

def plot_anomalies(forecasted):
    alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()
    interval = alt.Chart(forecasted).mark_area(interpolate="basis", color = '#7FC97F').encode(
    x=alt.X('ds:T',  title ='date'),
    y='yhat_upper',
    y2='yhat_lower',
    tooltip=['ds', 'fact', 'regions', 'az']).interactive().properties(title='Anomaly Detection')

    fact = alt.Chart(forecasted[forecasted.anomaly==0]).mark_circle(size=15, opacity=0.7, color = 'Black').encode(
        x='ds:T',
        y=alt.Y('fact', title='usage percent'),    
        tooltip=['ds', 'fact']).interactive()

    anomalies = alt.Chart(forecasted[forecasted.anomaly!=0]).mark_circle(size=30, color = 'Red').encode(
        x='ds:T',
        y=alt.Y('fact', title='usage percent'),    
        tooltip=['ds', 'fact', 'regions', 'az'],
        size = alt.Size( 'importance', legend=None)).interactive()

    return alt.layer(interval, fact, anomalies)
              .properties(width=870, height=350)
              .configure_title(fontSize=20)
```

I save the return object pred as pred.save('Name.html')

Comment: Please include a complete code snippet that reproduces your chart; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can definitely include that, but the issue is gone and it is working now. However, I still want to understand the core reason behind it and the concept

Answer (score 0):

No longer reproducible as per the comment of the OP. No reason provided as to why.